# make: *** No rule to make target `obj/main.o'. Stop

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on an SDL project for which I'm using a makefile to build it. I'm Doing this on windows with a MinGW w64 compiler and make.

My project structure looks something like this

```
proj
------>bin        #stores the executable
------>include    #stroes the external library include files
------>lib        #stores the lib files of the libraries
------>obj        #stores the .o files
------>src        #source files
makefile
```

and my makefile looks something like this

```
CC = g++
OUT = main
ODIR = ./obj
SDIR = ./src 
OUTDIR = ./bin
IDIR = ./include 
LDIR = ./lib
libs = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SDIR)/%.cpp,$(ODIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SDIR)/*.cpp))

$(ODIR)/%.o : $(SDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -I $(IDIR) -o $@ $^

$(OUTDIR)/% : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -L $(LDIR) -o $@ $^ $(libs)

.PHONY : run

run :
    $(OUTDIR)/$(OUT)
```

Initially, the makefile was working just fine, After I edited the makefile by editing the src variable and then un-did it the make files gives the error

```
make ./obj/main.o
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/main.o'.  Stop.
```

I tried renaming the file to MakeFile or a.mk and tried to run it, but even that does not help.

So what am I supposed to do to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a trailing space on this line:

```
SDIR = ./src
```

Remove it, and the prerequisite will be correct, and the makefile will work.

Comment: The importance of invisible characters in make cannot be stressed enough.